# Empty Slow Query Log

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Good afternoon,

we are trying to have access to our slow query log file at "/var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log" but it looks like the file is empty. The "my.cnf" file says "!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d", and inside that directory we have the following files:

```
mysql-clients.cnf;
server.cnf;
tokudb.cnf;
```

Looking at the "server.cnf" file it looks like it's set properly to write slow queries logs:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-5.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mysqld-5.5]

# These two groups are only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

[mariadb-5.5]
```

We've tried to SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'; but it didn't help. Any idea on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that it is really reading that file:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | head -33
```

You will probably see

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
```

followed by a list of file paths.

Comment: Rick, thanks this is the input: 

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf` - Does it mean is not reading server.cnf?

Comment: We've run `show variables like '%log%';` also and it looks like everything is fine:

`
slow_query_log | ON
slow_query_log_file | /var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log
long_query_time | 1.000000
min_examined_row_limit | 100
`

We' run also `select sleep(2);` and then `show status like 'Slow_queries';` but the result was: `Slow_queries  | 0`

Comment: `min_examined_row_limit = 100` filtered out your Sleep.

Comment: I've heard of `min_examined_row_limit` being non-zero only once before.  Seems unnecessary, and might eliminate queries that should be investigated.

Comment: I was thinking the same and set it to default (0)...still not logging but when running `select sleep(1);` and then `show status like 'Slow_queries;` I can now see the slow query after the sleep

Comment: I found out what was the problem: my.cnf file ownership was set to root instead of mysql...thanks anyway for your help